# How to get back wish shell after console hide

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a tcl wish shell as Tcl interpreter, where I executed `console hide` command. So console became invisible but process exists in task manager.
Is their any way to get console again. We have `console show` but where to run it?

[image: Attaching 8.6 wish shell with hide console option]

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a Tk gui that you can interact with?  If so, one option is to bind a key so that when pressed in your gui it opens the console.  E.g. if the toplevel gui window is "." and you choose key F2, add the following to your Tk code:

```
bind . <F2> {console show}
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit the heavy handed approach, but this works, if you have the [TWAPI](http://twapi.sourceforge.net/v4.0/ui.html#show_window) package and the PID of the process:

```
% package require twapi
4.1.27
```

Now lets get the Window handles available for the the PID:

```
% set w [twapi::get_toplevel_windows -pid 2432]
{197612 HWND} {132106 HWND} {590378 HWND} {132100 HWND} {327716 HWND}  {132098 HWND} {132094 HWND} {393624 HWND}
```

One of those windows should be the hidden console:

```
% foreach win $w {
>   puts "[twapi::get_window_text $win] Handle: $win"
> }
Konsole Handle: 197612 HWND
TclNotifier Handle: 132106 HWND
wish Handle: 590378 HWND
E Handle: 132100 HWND
M Handle: 327716 HWND
TtkMonitorWindow Handle: 132098 HWND
MSCTFIME UI Handle: 132094 HWND
Default IME Handle: 393624 HWND
```

This is a German windows, so for me the `Konsole` is the right one, lets show it again:

```
% twapi::show_window {197612 HWND}
1
```

And now the console is back and you can use it.

Comment: This is cool. But the only issue is that, once I have done hide console on the main wish shell, I have to relaunch the fresh new shell to run the above process, for making previous console visible.

Can we get rid of relaunching the new shell again?

Comment: If you can change the code, just use the code suggested in the other answer by @Colin. This answer assumed you have locked yourself out of the process and need to get a console back NOW.

Comment: my wish shell is bit customized one. thus the toplevel window is withdrawn at the time of launch itself. thats's why binding doesn't worked for me.

The work around i think is to change the state of toplevel window to normal, once hide console is done from wish file menu